# SQLite: foreign key referencing data in an FTS5 shadow table

Tags: sqlite, full-text-search, fts3, fts4

The [full-text search extensions](https://www.sqlite.org/fts5.html) of SQLite (FTS3, FTS4, FTS5) create shadow tables. E.g., if I create FTS5-table

```sql
CREATE VIRTUAL TABLE test USING fts5(textData);
```

that will also automatically create several real (non-virtual) tables, with `test_content` among them, which (apparently) stores the actual data inserted into the original virtual table `test`.

I know SQLite authors suggest that these shadow tables "should not be accessed directly by the user". But it's not clear from the docs if there are no any guarantee at all about behavior of these tables, or this advise concerns primarily attempts to directly `INSERT` or `UPDATE` on them. But what are the risks of reading from these tables?

Specifically - I need another (regular) table to have a `FOREIGN KEY` which references `rowid` of the virtual FTS5 table:

```sql
CREATE VIRTUAL TABLE test USING fts5(textData);
CREATE TABLE myTable (col1 INTEGER  REFERENCES test(rowid));
```

I couldn't find hints on that in the docs, but my own experiments showed that foreign key just doesn't work here - I still can delete records from the `test` table even though they are referenced from `myTable`. However, if instead I do

```sql
CREATE VIRTUAL TABLE test USING fts5(textData);
CREATE TABLE myTable (col1 INTEGER  REFERENCES test_content(id));
```

then everything seems to work as needed - I can't delete records from the virtual `test` table if they are referenced from `myTable`.

This works because, as follows from direct inspection, the `rowid` value of the `test` table is always equal to the `id` column value of the `test_content` table. Even when I specify `rowid` manually like in `INSERT INTO test (rowid, value) VALUES (424242, 'foobar');` - then a new row appears in the `test_content` with the corresponding content and the corresponding `id` equal to `424242` (even if no preceding records were ever in the table).

So basically, my question is - is this correspondence between the `rowid` of an FTS5-table and the `id` of the corresponding `<name>_content` shadow table guaranteed to hold? Or might this break in some cases or in future versions?

Comment: Can you give a hint on how to implement a `foreign key`-like constraint on FTS5 table? Say, I have a normal table with document IDs, and an FTS5 table with contents of those documents. The question is how to prevent deletion of a content from the FTS5-table if the corresponding document ID is present in the first table? I imagine this could be done with a `trigger`, but triggers also not supported by virtual tables (afaik).

Comment: Triggers do work, as I have used fts5 myself to create a "search" table for my database and used triggers to keep its data in sync with the rest of the database. HOWEVER, generally it's a better idea to solve this type of thing not on the database, but on whatever is calling your database. If you do web development and thus use the MVC pattern, do this in your controller, not your model (aka database).
The main reason for this would be readability and troubleshooting. Controller code tends to be easier to fix. If you need performance, triggers may be faster, you'd need to test that one.